# How to stop 0 doesn't allow of first character in some scenarios by using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jquery. I have form with two text boxes. In that i am restrict special characters.

Now i want stop `0` in some cases.

valid and invalid scenarios:

`000` - invalid

`01` or `0100`- invalid

`100` - valid

`0.44`- valid

`0.00` - invalid

```js
$('#minAmt').bind('paste', function() {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (!/^\d*(\.\d{1,2})+$/.test($(self).val())) $(self).val('');
  }, 0);
});
$('.minAmt').keypress(function(e) {
  var character = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
  var newValue = this.value + character;
  if (isNaN(newValue) || hasDecimalPlace(newValue, 3)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});

function hasDecimalPlace(value, x) {
  var pointIndex = value.indexOf('.');
  return pointIndex >= 0 && pointIndex < value.length - x;
}
$('#maxAmt').bind('paste', function() {

  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (!/^\d*(\.\d{1,2})+$/.test($(self).val())) $(self).val('');
  }, 0);
});
$('.minAmt').keypress(function(e) {
  var character = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
  var newValue = this.value + character;
  if (isNaN(newValue) || hasDecimalPlace(newValue, 3)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});

function hasDecimalPlace(value, x) {
  var pointIndex = value.indexOf('.');
  return pointIndex >= 0 && pointIndex < value.length - x;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label for="minAmt" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Min.Amount</label>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control minAmt" id="minAmt" name="minAmt" placeholder="Enter Min Amount" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label for="maxAmt" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Max.Amount</label>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control maxAmt" id="maxAmt" name="maxAmt" placeholder="Enter Max Amount" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: There is no class .minAmt and your JQuery targets that.Is it typo.

Comment: @shubham agrawal: Sorry small mistake. Please check it once...

Comment: jQuery bind is deprecated, use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: @Esko: i don't understanding what you say. I am not jquery expert yarrr :)

Comment: The definition of what is valid is not clear. Are you saying anything that a human would think of as `zero` is invalid?

Comment: It's pretty simple @Durga don't use bind, it's been replaced by on. Thats why it's [listed as depreacted on jquery](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) *Categories: **Deprecated > Deprecated 3.0** | Events > Event Handler Attachment*

Comment: invalid means textbox not accept that. Valid means it accept

Comment: Yes I know what valid means.... What is you definition of valid in this context...

Comment: @Durga : Hope your requirement is value is invalid if it starts with 0 and also if it starts with 0 after the decimal.

try this regex, as per your request `^([1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|[0]*\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)$` this one will validate match only `100` and `0.44`

Comment: @Liam: Actually amount is not started with zero na?. So that's y i am asking how to stop zero in first character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope your requirement is : value is invalid if it starts with `0` and also if it starts with `0` after the decimal.

As per your request

```
000 - invalid
01 or 0100- invalid
100 - valid
0.44- valid
0.00 - invalid
```

Use this regex,

```
^([1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|[0]*\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)$
```

You will get the output as

```
100 - valid
0.44- valid
```

Comment: Okay. How can restrict `0` in first value

Comment: Use this,

`$("#input").on("keypress keyup",function(){
    if($(this).val() == '0'){
      $(this).val('');  
    }
});`